# JavaScript Check Hour

Tags: javascript, html

I need some help please, if you can, I need to do a program, with two files, one HTML and one JS that contains the functoin CheckTime().
I need to use in the HTML file a

that ask me what time it is. Then when I click on a button Insert Hour, I have to insert the time, but only the hour, manually inserted, inside the prompt box, then click ok, and then if I click ok the function should show me a "GOOD MORNING TEXT" if its <11 or Good Afternoon.
Can you help me please?

```
<html>
<head><title> Ex 1 </title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ex1.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<p> What time is it? </p>
<button onclick="checkTime()">What time is it?</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and then the JS file is like this

```
window.onload = checkTime;
var hour;
function checkTime()
{
    var hour = prompt("What time is it?");
if (hour < 11) {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good Morning!"
}
else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon!"
}
```

Comment: You've solved it yourself in your example. Except for a missing `}` at the end and the fact that `window.onload=checkTime` makes it run as soon as the page loads. What's the issue?

Comment: also missing the div(or any other element) that you are refrancing in the code (with id demo)

Answer (score 0):

Missing a closing bracket from your checkTime function! And missing an element with `id="demo"`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following div tag into the body tag of the HTML:

```
<div id="demo">

</div>
```

Then make sure in the JavaScript too to close the checkTime function at the end add the missing }

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the element with id **demo**

```js
window.onload = checkTime;
var hour;

function checkTime() {
  var hour = prompt("What time is it?");
  if (hour < 11) {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good Morning!"
  } else {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Good Afternoon!"
  }
}
```

```html
<p> What time is it? </p>
<button onclick="checkTime()">What time is it?</button>

<p id="demo"></p>
```